# JavaScript Asynchronous in Redux..?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

Action in fuction (action for data imported from firstore) 
Here you get index data.

```
export async function getUserIndex (data){


    let db = loadFB().firestore();
    console.log(data)
    let date = moment(data).utc().format()
    let query = db.collection('users').where("create_date", ">", date)
    console.log(query)
    return await query.get().then(docs=>{
        let result =  docs.size
        console.log("result!!", result)
        return  result
    })
}
```

components in function

```
    async getuserIndex_component(date){
        let number =""
        number = await userAction.getUserIndex(date)
        console.log("number",number)
        return await number
    }
```

```
const {user_list} = this.props; //user_list = [{id:aa, pw:bb},{id:cc, pw:dd}...} data
        let data = user_list
        let groups = {} 
        let number =0
        for (let index_data of data) {
            let date = moment(index_data.create_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD").slice(0, 10)

            let index = this.getuserIndex_component(date) //<==here log Promise{<pendding>}
            console.log(index)            
            if (groups[date]) {   
                let group = groups[date];
                group.push({ index: index-number, ...index_data });    
            } else {
                number =0;
                groups[date] = [{ index:  index-number, ...index_data }]
            }
            number++;
        }
        const dates = Object.keys(groups)
        const user_list_result = []
         for (let date of dates) {   
            user_list_result.push(...(groups[date]))
        }

return(...)
```

I am using redux. in action
Made a "getUserIndex()."

The component will then access the "getUserIndex" and retrieve data. But there is only pending in the console.log, and the data I want does not appear.

In this situation, I would like to know how to deal with async in for of.

I want to know what part I'm making a mistake.

In summary, functions in components are executed later than the render. So the index in the render does not contain the data. What is the solution to this?

Comment: Your calling `getuserIndex_component` but the function is `getuserIndex_components` with an 's' on the end. I'm assuming this is just a typo on your demo? Or is there another function somewhere?

Comment: As `getuserIndex_component` is asynchronous you will just receive a promise. The simple option would be to `await` the call, however, that would only let one run at a time. Instead, I would recommend pushing all of the promises into an array and using `Promise.all()` after the loop.

Comment: It's a typo. I've modified it.

Comment: "pushing all of the promises into an array and using Promise.all() after the loop" I don't know what you mean. Can you expand more by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `getuserIndex_component` is asynchronous, it will return a promise. You will need to wait for that promise to resolve before the `index` result is available.

Firstly, you should be able to simplify `getuserIndex_component` to

```js
async getuserIndex_component(date) {
  let number = await userAction.getUserIndex(date)
  console.log("number", number)
  return number
}
```

And when you remove the `console.log` it could simply be

```js
async getuserIndex_component(date) {
  return userAction.getUserIndex(date)
}
```

As I mentioned in the comments. You can send off all of the async calls, then just wait for all of the promises to resolve via `Promise.all`.

Something like this. (I couldn't test any of this, but it should demonstrate the general idea.)

```js
const { user_list } = this.props; //user_list = [{id:aa, pw:bb},{id:cc, pw:dd}...} data
let data = user_list
let groups = {}
let number = 0

const dates = []
const promises = data.map((index_data) => {
  const date = moment(index_data.create_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD").slice(0, 10)
  dates.push(date) // To use after all promises resolve.
  return this.getuserIndex_component(date) // The index promise.
})

const indexes = await Promise.all(promises)

for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  const index = indexes[i]
  const date = dates[i]

  console.log(index)
  if (groups[date]) {
    let group = groups[date];
    group.push({
      index: index - number,
      ...index_data
    });
  } else {
    number = 0;
    groups[date] = [{
      index: index - number,
      ...index_data
    }]
  }
  number++;
}
const dates = Object.keys(groups)
const user_list_result = []
for (let date of dates) {
  user_list_result.push(...(groups[date]))
}

return (...)
```

Comment: thank, but  An error is sent from the Await classification in front of promise.
  const indexes = **await** Promise.all(promises)                                                                                      
                                 **^**

Comment: 'await' can only be used inside an async function, and a top-level function cannot be async.  I can't teach all of this here (and it's off-topic, anyway), but start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: @이창훈 as I said, This was to demonstrate the general idea. You didn't provide any context of what function this is in, or if it was async. So inevitably will need some modifications.